# Simple tournament bracket system

Tags: excel

I'm making a simple tournament bracket system..

So basically I have table A, in it are two values. 
I have a cell where one of the value is defined.

I need to look up that value in table A and copy the OTHER value to a new cell..???

So table has value "Hello" and "World". In the lookup cell i have the word "Hello". Now I need the new cell to be "World".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a table 2 x 4 in the cells A1:B4, where one of the pairs is "Hello" and "World", the following function will fetch you "World":

```
=VLOOKUP("Hello", A1:B4, 2)
```

Comment: And remeber that thoug spreadsheets offer comfort, they also limit you. Learn a real computer language such as Python or Ruby, and you will handle more difficult tasks with ease.